# maven central vs cloudera repository for hadoop core

Tags: maven, hadoop, cloudera, maven-central

I'm trying to include hadoop-core from a maven repository, and there are two repositories that contain it, maven central and the cloudera maven repository. Is there a reason to choose one over the other? They use different versioning too - in maven central, hadoop core is at 1.2.1 and in cloudera there are versions like hadoop-core-0.20.2-cdh3u6.

I can't seem to figure out what the differences are here. Any guidance?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases maven central have released versions only. The case you mentioned seems like that cloudera is also having intermediate/classified versions as well.

Whenever possible it is good to use maven centeral because otherwise your build will be looking in multiple repos for artifacts.

Comment: Kindly don't forget to accept the answer if it clarified your question.

Comment: I know this is generally the case, but Cloudera also has released versions. They are part of the Cloudera bundle. This is a specific question about the Cloudera bundle of hadoop, not a general question of when to use maven central, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: There may be some difference between them. I encountered some APIs difference in my work. I recommend that using the same version jar of your hadoop cluster. For example, if your hadoop cluster is CDH, cloudera repository is a better option.